# Jmeter | SAP Fiori | Load Test | Blank Response Body | Response Code 200 OK

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, sap-fiori

I am doing load testing of SAP Fiori app using Jmeter tool. The scripts are working fine with multiple users but during load testing the same scripts throw errors as the response body received is blank for most of the requests. However, the response code for the same request is 200 OK. Error because of the response assertion fails as the response received is empty and the check is put on the received text only.

[Sample Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9YfQ.png)

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltEhx.png)

Tried increasing the timeout, changing implementation of the request but, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

12 kilobytes of response don't seem "blank" to me:

[image]

so I can think only of the situation where JMeter is overloaded and the Response Assertion fails to properly work with the response data.

So consider following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and ensure that JMeter is properly configured for high loads and there are no errors in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

If you won't be able to conduct the required load from a single machine there is a possibility to run JMeter tests in [distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter).

Comment: hi Dmitri, thank you for the response. i will keep above pointers in mind for future. however, i had distributed the load via 7 different machines.

also, i guess i found the issue with the help of the DB team. the issue was that i was using same user id and same sales order for editing at the same time. so may be because of that Jmeter was loading blank response body. for now issue is resolved.

thanks!